# How do I remove logo from a footline in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

In PaloAlto theme a logo is inserted into the footline. It is too big and doesn't look good. How can I remove it, without destroying all the template?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{beamerthemelined}
 \usetheme{PaloAlto}
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

 \logo
 {
    \includegraphics[height = 0.8cm]{Slonko.png}
    \includegraphics[height = 0.8cm]{logo_pw_white_v2.png}
 }
 \title [App]{Application}
 \author[a]{author1 \inst{1}}
 \institute{\inst{1} Institute}
 \date{}

 \begin{document}

    \frame{\titlepage}

 \end{document}
```

[image: Title page]

I want to have logos in the sidebar and remove them from the footline.

Comment: There should be a logo by default. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Anyway, try `\logo{}` to disable the logo. Also `\let\insertlogo\relax` might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logo in the foot line seems to be hardcoded in `beamerthemelined` (which is an old, deprecated theme) and not easily removable. You could copy the source code to your file and edit the logo out. The corresponding command is 
`\usebeamertemplate*{logo}`.
You could set the `logo` template to empty, but this would remove the logo everywhere. The bigger logo in the upper left corner is inserted using `\insertlogo` which is simply defined to `\usebeamertemplate*{logo}`. So you could do the following hack: set the `logo` template to empty and redefine `\insertlogo` to insert the logo directly. This offends the theme interface of `beamer` but works OK in my test.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{beamerthemelined}
 \usetheme{PaloAlto}
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

 \def\insertlogo
 {%
    \includegraphics[height = 0.8cm]{Slonko}
    \includegraphics[height = 0.8cm]{logo_pw_white_v2}
 }
 \title [App]{Application}
 \author[a]{author1 \inst{1}}
 \institute{\inst{1} Institute}
 \date{}

 \setbeamertemplate{logo}{}
 \begin{document}

    \frame{\titlepage}
    \frame{}

 \end{document}
```